# Build query 'average amount by month' with filling gaps from previous month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem. I need to build report query to calculate average amount by month. 
If user from account does not buy anything in this month I should use `amount` from previous month.

This is my data: As you can see I have one account operation on July (2014-07) and one operation in August (2014-08).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `value_hist` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_channel_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:money)(DC2Type:money)',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

INSERT INTO `value_hist` (`id`, `account_id`, `data_channel_id`, `status`, `amount`, `created_at`)
VALUES
 (28, 19, 2, 0, 100.0000, '2014-08-22 14:59:47'),
 (29, 19, 2, 0, 11.0000,  '2014-09-22 15:05:36'),
 (30, 19, 2, 0, 22.0000,  '2014-09-22 15:10:59'),
 (31, 19, 2, 0, 0.0000,   '2014-09-22 15:14:19'),
 (32, 19, 2, 0, 22.0000,  '2014-09-22 15:15:58'),
 (33, 19, 2, 0, 0.0000,   '2014-09-22 15:17:29'),
 (34, 1, 2, 0, 50.0000,   '2014-07-22 15:20:10'),
 (35, 1, 2, 0, 0.0000,    '2014-09-22 15:23:37'),
 (36, 1, 2, 0, 100.0000,  '2014-09-22 15:23:39'),
 (37, 1, 2, 1, 0.0000,    '2014-09-22 15:30:53'),
 (38, 19, 2, 0, 100.0000, '2014-09-22 15:30:53'),
 (39, 28, 2, 1, 0.0000,   '2014-09-22 15:36:44'),
 (40, 19, 2, 1, 0.0000,   '2014-09-22 15:45:24'),
 (41, 6, 2, 0, 0.0000,    '2014-09-22 15:48:54'),
 (42, 6, 2, 0, 200.0000,  '2014-09-22 15:49:34'),
 (43, 6, 2, 1, 33.0000,   '2014-09-22 15:50:18');
```

I have built a query. Which can get average value from each month

```
SELECT 
    data_channel_id,
    test2.monthaa,
    AVG(h1.amount) as amount
FROM
    value_hist h1
    JOIN (
     SELECT  MAX(dd.`id`) as id, EXTRACT(month from dd.created_at) as monthaa
     FROM value_hist dd 
     where dd.created_at > '01.01.2014' 
     GROUP BY  data_channel_id,  dd.account_id, monthaa
    ) test2 ON test2.id =  h1.id
WHERE
    created_at > '01.01.2014'
GROUP BY data_channel_id, monthaa
```

The result return average value from each month

```
| channel | month | amount |
| 2       | 7     | 50.0000|
| 2       | 8     | 100.000|
| 2       | 9     | 8.25000|
```

But I should get this result, I should consider previous month `amount`. For example (100 + 50) / 2, because account 1 did not buy in August (2014-08)

```
| channel | month | amount |
| 2       | 7     | 50.0000|
| 2       | 8     | 75.0000|
| 2       | 9     | 8.25000|
```

Update: There was only one account in July(7) thus amout equal to 50.00; (50.00 / 1 = 50.00).
In August(8) second account has come therefore amount equal to 75.00; ((100.00 + 50) / 2 = 75.00) because I have two accounts in August(8).

Comment: Why is month 7 50 and not 12.5?  You have four people in the data.

Comment: This is confusing, as far as I can tell, your original query is averaging each month's last inserted transaction amount for each account id. Is this correct? You make no mention of this complexity in the question.. I'm guessing you want to use the last inserted amount from the previous month if there is no transaction for a month for a particular user. I'd be expecting (0,0,0,50)/4 = 12.5, (0,0,50,100)/4=37.5, 8.25 by that logic, but I can't for the life of me imagine why you'd want to calculate an average like this!

Comment: Ah, worked it out, the status is the balance at the end of the transaction.. and the first transaction for each user represents the opening of the account. For the first month there is only one account, and for the second there are two and the third four. You want the average of each existing account's balance at the end of the month. Correct?

Comment: 2 [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff):
Because in 7 month was only one account. And second account was added in 8 month.

Comment: 2 [Arth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1051628/arth) Yes you are right. For each month for existing accounts( 7 - one account, 8 - two accounts, etc)